# Azure Devops Release Pipeline Python Module Not Found

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm attempting to configure a release pipeline for my project. One of the jobs is a simple bash script used to publish the code to PyPI:

```
python3 -V

python3 setup.py build && python3 setup.py sdist

twine upload dist/wordsearch*.tar.gz --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH)
```

However when I run create a release I receive the following error:

```
2018-12-13T00:28:28.8474589Z ##[section]Starting: Publish Script
2018-12-13T00:28:28.8478332Z ==============================================================================
2018-12-13T00:28:28.8478459Z Task         : Bash
2018-12-13T00:28:28.8478532Z Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
2018-12-13T00:28:28.8478635Z Version      : 3.142.2
2018-12-13T00:28:28.8478736Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-12-13T00:28:28.8478819Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613738)
2018-12-13T00:28:28.8478963Z ==============================================================================
2018-12-13T00:28:29.5748147Z Generating script.
2018-12-13T00:28:29.5751467Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/0e077afa-4419-4ee3-9aa8-c1b9b1f16b85.sh
2018-12-13T00:28:29.5751681Z Python 3.5.2
2018-12-13T00:28:29.7992675Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-12-13T00:28:29.8002462Z   File "setup.py", line 17, in <module>
2018-12-13T00:28:29.8002681Z     from setuptools import setup, find_packages
2018-12-13T00:28:29.8003469Z ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'
2018-12-13T00:28:29.8108863Z /home/vsts/work/_temp/0e077afa-4419-4ee3-9aa8-c1b9b1f16b85.sh: line 5: twine: command not found
2018-12-13T00:28:29.8229014Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.
2018-12-13T00:28:29.8257310Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish Script
```

What I gathered, was that I'm missing setuptools, and twine. What's unusual is that setuptools should be a built in to the Python library, and yet there is an import error.

I have a Twine Authentication job prior to the script, and have verified that the setup.py file exists:

[image]

Am I missing a component, or have I overlooked something? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using hosted agent or your own custom agent ?

Comment: I am using Hosted Ubuntu 1604

Comment: The error is telling that `twine` command is not found, so it either not installed (or) the `path` variable doesn't aware of the twine . So check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pypi?view=vsts&tabs=designer) to install it also check the path variable by `echo $PATH`

Comment: I added a script before the Twine Authenticate; the setuptools error went away, but there was still a `twine command not found` error. Here is my path: `"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

Answer (score 2):

In order to accomplish this, you will need to use `python -m twine` instead of the plain 'twine' command. 'pip install' places the twine binary inside a location of the user running on the agent which isn't in $PATH (something like /home/vsts/.local/bin).

For similar issues you can place debug steps with shell commands such as `find ~ -name twine && echo $PATH`